# How To Get Image Move A Certain Distance Until Button Is Pressed Again

Tags: java, animation, javafx

So I've implemented a sliding mechanism in my simple game where if the player press the DOWN arrow then the RIGHT arrow the player will "slide" until either the RIGHT arrow or DOWN arrow is released . I have been trying to get the game to make it instead like this:

Player press DOWN and then RIGHT KEY
Player character (sprite) will "slide" for "x(e.g 2 )" second
Player then has to press DOWN and then RIGHT KEY to start sliding again

My Code:

```
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480, Color.ALICEBLUE);

    final Image runningninjap1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("runningninja.png"));
    final ImageView ninja1 = new ImageView(runningninjap1);
    final Image runningninjaleftp1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("runningninjaleft.png"));
    Image tempground = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ground.png"));
    Image tempground2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ground.png"));
    final Image imgjumpingninja = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("jumpingninja.png"));
    final Image imgjumpingninjaleft = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("jumpingninjaleft.png"));
    final Image imgcrouchingninja = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("crounchingninja.png"));

    final Image imgcrouchingninjaleft = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("crounchingninjaleft.png"));
    final Image imgninjafalling = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("fallingninja.png"));
    final Image imgninjafallingleft = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("fallingleft.png"));
    final Image test = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("nj.png"));
    final Image imgninjaslidingright = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("slidingninja_1.png"));
    final Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

    r.setX(rectx);
    r.setY(recty);
    r.setWidth(50);
    r.setHeight(100);
    r.setArcWidth(20);
    r.setArcHeight(20);

    Button button = new Button();
    ninjarun1 = new ImageView(runningninjap1);
    ninjarun1.setLayoutX(ninjax);
    ninjarun1.setLayoutY(ninjay);
    iview2 = new ImageView(tempground);
    iview2.setLayoutX(backgroundx);
    iview2.setLayoutY(backgroundy);
    iview3 = new ImageView(tempground2);
    iview3.setLayoutX(555);
    iview3.setLayoutY(backgroundy);
    iview4 = new ImageView(imgjumpingninja);
    iview4.setLayoutX(aix);
    iview4.setLayoutY(aiy);
    final Group ninja;
    ninja = new Group(ninja1);

    root.getChildren().addAll(iview2, iview3, button, ninjarun1);
    primaryStage.setTitle("A basic window");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    //keypressed
    button.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {

                directionleft = true;
                dashleft = true;
                ninjax = ninjax - 10;

                ninjarun1.setLayoutX(ninjax);
            }

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                crouching = true;

            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {

                if (ninjay > 340) {
                    jumpforce = -15;

                }
                ninjarun1.setLayoutY(ninjay);

            }

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {

                ninjax = ninjax + 10;
                directionleft = false;

                runningframes = runningframes + 1;

            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT && crouching == true) {
                sliding = true;

            } else {
                sliding = false;
            }
            if (runningframes > 0) {
                rightcycle = true;
            }
            ninjarun1.setLayoutY(ninjax);

            if (runningframes > 16) {
                runningframes = 0;

            }

        }

    });
   //keyreleased

    button.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                crouching = false;

            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                sliding = false;

            }

        }

    });
    //physics engine

    new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override

        public void handle(long now) {

            if (ninjarun1.getBoundsInParent().intersects(iview2.getBoundsInParent())) {

                groundforce = -gravity;

            } else {
                groundforce = 0;

            }

            if (jumpforce < 0) {

                ninjay = ninjay - (-gravity) + jumpforce + groundforce;

                if (directionleft == true) {
                    ninjax = ninjax - 3;
                } else if (directionleft == false) {
                    ninjax = ninjax + 3;
                }

                jumpforce = jumpforce + 1;
                jumping = true;
            } else if ((ninjay < 340)) {
                ninjay = ninjay - (gravity) + jumpforce + groundforce;

                if (directionleft == true) {
                    ninjax = ninjax - 3;
                } else if (directionleft == false) {
                    ninjax = ninjax + 3;
                }
                falling = true;
            } else {

                jumping = false;
            }

            ninjarun1.setLayoutY(ninjay);
            ninjarun1.setLayoutX(ninjax);

            //directionleft
            if (directionleft == true) {
                ninjarun1.setImage(runningninjaleftp1);
                //leftjumping
                if ((jumping == true)) {
                    ninjarun1.setImage(imgjumpingninjaleft);
                    if (jumpforce == 0) {
                        ninjarun1.setImage(imgninjafallingleft);
                    }
                } //leftrunning
                else if ((jumping == false)) {
                    ninjarun1.setImage(runningninjaleftp1);

                    //leftcrouching
                    if (crouching == true) {
                        ninjarun1.setImage(imgcrouchingninjaleft);
                    } else if (crouching == false) {
                        ninjarun1.setImage(runningninjaleftp1);
                    }
                }

            } //directionright
            else if (directionleft == false) {

                //rightjumping
                if ((jumping == true)) {
                    ninjarun1.setImage(imgjumpingninja);
                    if (jumpforce == 0) {
                        ninjarun1.setImage(imgninjafalling);
                    }

                } //rightrunning 
                else if ((jumping == false)) {

                    //rightcouching
                    if (crouching == true) {

                        ninjarun1.setImage(imgcrouchingninja);

                        if (sliding == true) {
                            ninjarun1.setImage(imgninjaslidingright);
                            ninjax = ninjax + 10;
                            slidingtime = slidingtime - 1;
                            System.out.println("ninjax: " + ninjax);

                        }

                    }

                    if ((crouching == false)) {
                        ninjarun1.setImage(runningninjap1);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }.start();

}
```